# How can I run the below command line code with gcc?

Tags: c, gcc, command-line, clang

I downloaded a folder from cloud which contains some `.c`and  `.h` files.

```
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----          3/2/2022   2:05 PM           1755 bmp.h
-a----          3/2/2022   2:05 PM           3490 filter.c
-a----          3/2/2022   2:06 PM           4431 helpers.c
-a----          3/2/2022   2:06 PM            385 helpers.h
-a----          3/2/2022   2:41 PM       34292790 img1.bmp
-a----         2/28/2022   9:51 PM            179 Makefile
-a----          3/2/2022   2:01 PM              0 out.bmp
```

And inside **Makefile** was this code

```
filter:
    clang -ggdb3 -O0 -Qunused-arguments -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow -lm -o filter filter.c helpers.c
```

The purpose of these files combinedly is to apply filters to an image file. The cloud (IDE) was using clang. I use gcc and am now facing problems running the program locally since I don't have clang installed.

```
working dir> gcc filter.c -o filter
working dir> .\filter.exe -b img1.bmp out.bmp
Unsupported file format.
```

What can I do besides installing clang?

Comment: I'd have to look up all options to be 100% sure, but you can likely just swap `clang` with `gcc`. Try it and see where/if it whines.

Comment: The only command-line argument that gives me problems with `gcc` is `-Qunused-arguments`, where `-Wno-` is used instead of `-Q`.

Comment: You've completely changed your question by adding that you're able to compile it, it's just not running properly.

Comment: ...In other words, _change your Makefile_ to frob GCC correctly instead of Clang. Then run `make` (Linux) / `mingw32-make` (Windows).

Comment: @Dúthomhas so the problem is in Makefile then?

Comment: What makes you think the message “Unsupported file format.” means you cannot run the program? In other words, what makes you think that message is the command-line interpreter telling you it cannot run the program, rather than the program running and telling you the file you asked it to process has an unsupported file format?

Comment: @Diwas_lufy try to remplace `clang` with `gcc` in `Makefile`, then run `mingw32-make`. BTW what is your platform?

Comment: The program runs — it just doesn't like one of the files it is given to process.  Look at the instructions for how to use the program.  Maybe it doesn't like the empty file?

Comment: In the cloud, _filter.c_ includes `"helpers.h"` where all function prototypes are defined. All the function code is inside _helpers.c_. Now the problem is that _filter.c_ doesnot include `"helpers.c"` and I suppose, is linking to helpers.c via _makefile_ . In the above compilation output, I had changed the _filter.c_ to include `"helpers.c"` rather than `"helpers.h"` because _helpers.h_ was already included in the _helpers.c_  file so that the functions would work. If I include `"helpers.h"` instead of `"helpers.c"` in _filter.c_ hoping that the cmd line linking works, it doesn't.

Comment: Add "helpers.c" to the command line: `gcc filter.c helpers.c -o filter` as the given command for clang does. It is a strategic error to include the implementation instead of the header.